# Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли пропустить итерацию map или forEach javascript?

Tags: javascript

Например, у меня есть массив чисел `number` и слева направо точки их слияния `isMergeNumbers` в булевом значении.

```js
// true или false говорят, делать ли слияние
// этого значения со следующем или нет.
// 1,2 - true, 2,4 - false;
let isMergeNumbers = [true, false, false, true];
let numbers = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5];
```

и я хочу пройтись по массиву `numbers` методом `map` например и по индексу проверять значения `isMergeNumbers`, если `true` - возвращать новое ***число(текущее число + следующее)*** и пропустить следующую итерацию, а если `false`, то просто возвращать текущее значение. И на выходе получить новый массив
типа:

```
number = [3,4,8];
```

Comment: Странно, тогда `[3,4,3,8]` должен быть результат? Почему на второе false 3 не записывается?

Comment: @Leonid у меня ситуация сложнее, данный пример я сделал просто для упращения. Изначально я определяю слева на право нужно ли мне соединять элементы массива или нет. И потом уже нужно соединить. поэтому все правильно. слева на право у 5 значений 4 точки пересечения.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Может логичнее тогда `isMergeNumbers` прогонять через `map`?

```js
let isMergeNumbers = [true, false, false, true]; // true или false говорят, делать ли слияние этого значения со следующем или нет. 1,2 - true, 2,4 - false;
let numbers = [1,2,4,3,5];

let i = 0;

let result = isMergeNumbers.map(condition => {
  let num = 0;
  if(condition){
     num = numbers[i++] + (numbers[i++] || 0); // Если я здесь изменю, то будет то же самое, никакой разницы.
  } else {
    num = numbers[i++];
  }
  return num;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Да можно, об этом я чет не подумал). Спасибо за пример. Пример который по ниже с редьюсером лучше подходит к моей ситуации)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `reduce`

```js
let isMergeNumbers = [true, false, false, true];
let numbers = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5];
let idx = 0;
res = isMergeNumbers.reduce(function(res, val) {
  let cur = numbers[idx++] || 0;
  if (val) {
    cur += numbers[idx++] || 0;
  }
  res.push(cur);
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: в данном случае получается 3,4,3,5 а результатом должно быть 3,4,8

Comment: @Kanubis Если должно быть 3,4,8, значит у вас ошибка либо в описании алгоритма, либо в исходных данных. Тем более, что вы приняли ответ, который выводит тот же результат